# using HashMap with subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap

```
 private HashMap<String, SuperClass> mapOfRoles = new HashMap();
 public void X()
  {
        mapOfRoles.put(String, SubClassA);
        mapOfRoles.put(String, SubClassB);
  }
```

error: no suitable method found for put(String,Wolf)
            playerRolesMap.put(listOfPlayers.get(0), new Wolf(listOfPlayers.get(0)));
    method HashMap.put(String,Role) is not applicable
      (actual argument Wolf cannot be converted to Role by method invocation conversion)

Where Wolf is a subclass of Role

I'm trying to write a program where I need to access methods that are written into a subclass, however this does not compile as the subclass cannot be cast back into the superclass, with the compiler saying: actual argument subclassA cannot be converted to Superclass by method invocation conversion)

At the moment I can't see another way to implement my code to be able to dynamically retrieve the objects. Most of the time the methods that are going to be called for the subclasses are contained within the superclass, however each subclass has a few methods that only relate to it.

Is there a design flaw that can be rectified.

Comment: *"the subclass cannot be cast back into the superclass"*? Perhaps you could show an actual complete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: actual argument subclass cannot be converted to superclass by method invocation conversion - due to different methods and variables that only exist in the subclass

Comment: Show us your code, and the complete and exact error message.

Comment: It should work.. I don't think any issue.. Are you passing Class Name or Instance of Class

Answer (score 5):

Of course you [can do what you are trying](http://ideone.com/WxLgGl). However you should put **instances** of `String` and `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` into the map.

Answer (score 0):

[Generics Bounded Wild Card](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I dó not know if this is the answer you are looking for but you could create a common interface and use that as reference instead! I believe that is called polymorphismen !